# how to apply jquery lazy loading for second set of images?

Tags: jquery

I am using this jquery's lazy loader plugin to lazy load bunch of thumbnails.
What will happen if I apply lazy loader to smaller thumbnail images first,
and then dynamically change those smaller thumbnail images to something larger by changing src attribute of img.

I want to implement this zoom in/zoom out feature to thumbnail images, 
how do u make this lazy loading work for those larger image which will load after initial smaller ones ?